# c++ windows service Without ATL

Tags: visual-c++, service, wizard

Does any one knowns any good visual studio wizard for creating a Windows NT Service without the use of ATL. I don't need to implement any COM interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a wizard to create a service. A service DLL is just a normal DLL which exposes some special functions which are called by windows to initialize, start and stop the service.

You can read more about creating a basic service [here](http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/9857)